# Can I change ethernet settings of Mac OS X system mounted via Firewire?

Tags: macos, networking, ethernet

I have a Mac Pro that has been brought from our office to my home.  The Mac Pro is configured with a static IP address for the office, which uses a completely different network range than I have at my house.  This machine has been running headless in a rack for some time and I don't have a monitor at home I can hook it up to, so I can't boot it up and change its network address via the ordinary user interface.

What I do have is a Firewire cable, and I've been able to boot the system into target disk mode and mount its hard drive on an iMac we have here.

Can anyone tell me what file(s) I need to edit on the Mac Pro so I can change the IP settings for en0 (address, network, netmask, gateway, dns server)?  On Debian for example I'd just edit /etc/network/interfaces so I'm wondering if there's a plist or other system file that stores this information.

I have ARD running on the Mac Pro so if I can give it an address on my home network I could access it via Remote Desktop.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file responsible is:

> /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

This file should be XML, therefore it's easy to edit.

The `NetworkServices` dictionary tree will contain entries for each connection. Find the one with the static IP and change it here – it's the `IPv4` child dictionary you want to edit.

So, if you want to go from a static IP …

> [image]

… to DHCP assignment, change the tree as follows:

> [image]

Comment: I discovered that just as you answered and was in the process of answering my own question.  Thank you!